# fetching values in drop down list from one table and saving it to another table for many to many association in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have two models User and Role which have third model user_role.  I want to assign some roles to user while creating. A user can have many roles and a role can be assigned to many users. I have created roles like manager and admin in Roles table.Now I need to show these saved records in drop down list on user page as while creating user. There is many to many association between User and Role model.

What I have done: I have saved data as role name like manager,hr or amdin in Roles table.

Doubuts: Now I want to show these saved records in drop down list on user page while creating user and want to save with user records. I dont know how to fetch Roles table data on user page in drop down list and then save it to Role table.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :roles,  :through => :role_users
 has_many :roles_users
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
  :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :is_admin, :contact_no, :birth_date,
   :joining_date, :is_active, :is_hr, :is_manager, :user_code, :designation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

**role.rb**

```
  class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
      has_many :users,  :through => :role_users
      has_many :role_users
    end

role_user.rb



 class RolesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :role_id, :user_id
      belongs_to :user 
      belongs_to :role
    end
```

**roles_controller.rb**

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize_admin!

    def index
        @roles = Role.all
    end

    def new
     @role = Role.new 
    end

    def create
      @role  = Role.new(params[:role])
         if @role.save
           flash[:success] = "role created!"
           redirect_to role_path(@role)
       else
            render 'new' 
        end 
    end

    def show
      @role = Role.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
      @role = Role.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @role = Role.find(params[:id])
    if @role.update_attributes(params[:role])
        flash.notice = "Role #{@role.name} has been updated"
        redirect_to role_path(@role)
    else 
       render 'edit'
    end
   end 

    def destroy
      @role = Role.find(params[:id])
      @role.destroy
     redirect_to action:  'index' 
    end
end
```

Basically I want to fetch data from Roles table in to drop down list on Users table and want to save while creating user. Can any one help me. Pleas let me know , if you need more code to be pasted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on your user object called 'role_ids=' that allows you to assign an array to this.  If the drop down is a multi, it will submit a param for the user that looks like this in your params object:

```
params => { :user => { :role_ids => [1,2,3] } }
```

In your form, you would create the drop down like this

```
<%= f.select 'role_ids[]', @roles.map{|r| [r.name, r.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

Give this a try to see if it works for you...

**EDIT**

The braces are not needed here...

```
<%= f.select :role_ids, @roles.map{|r| [r.name, r.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

Comment: hi Swards, I tried with your suggestion, but I am getting following error:--  NoMethodError in Admin/users#new

Showing /home/vinay/workspace/merlin_vertis/app/views/admin/users/_form.html.erb where line #79 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: @VSiingh Try replacing `@roles.map` with `Role.all.map`, it isn't necessary to use an instance variable in this case. As for saving the association in your create action, I think you'll need something like `@users.role_users << Role.find(params[:user][role_ids])`

Comment: hi @Swards, after usign Role.all.map, now i am getting "undefined method `role_id[]' for #<User:0xa434fb8>" error. Anay suggestion. Is this role_ids[] or role_id[].

Comment: @VSiingh - it's plural.  It's a dynamic method based on the association you set up with has_many roles.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has_many

Comment: hi @Cyle, after usign Role.all.map, now i am getting "undefined method `role_id[]' for #<User:0xa434fb8>" error. Anay suggestion. Is this role_ids[] or role_id[].

Comment: @VSiingh - did you try role_ids[]?

Comment: hi @Swards ,  role_ids[] did not work. I am getting  "undefined method `role_id[]' for #<User:0xa434fb8>" error. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Where are you using role_id (singular)?  Is there a line number associated with the error?  Can you post your form code?

Comment: hi @Swards ,  following is link for _form.html.erb code on gist:- https://gist.github.com/Vinay50/ee7fbc9b5a202307fdc3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30805/discussion-between-vsiingh-and-swards)

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by using  <%= select_tag "role_id", options_from_collection_for_select( Role.all, "id", "name") %>.